# Is it possible to have Screen Compatibility Mode turned on only for xlarge not for large screens?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, compatibility

I am working on this Android app which is supposed to use the same layout for normal and large screen devices. But for all the screen sizes fall into xlarge bracket I want the system to use the Screen compatibility mode as described by this Android [document.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html)

In this document, it clearly says that:

> By default, screen compatibility mode for devices running Android 3.2
>   and higher is offered to users as an optional feature when one of the
>   following is true:
>
> - Your application has set both android:minSdkVersion and    android:targetSdkVersion to "10" or lower and does not explicitly
>     declare support for large screens using the 
>     element.
> - Your application has set either android:minSdkVersion or    android:targetSdkVersion to "11" or higher and explicitly declares
>     that it does not support large screens, using the 
>     element.

I have these tags in my manifest:

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
           android:targetSdkVersion="20"/>

     <supports-screens  android:resizeable="false"
                        android:normalScreens="true"
                        android:largeScreens="true"
                        android:xlargeScreens="false"
                        android:smallScreens="false"/>
```

And I suppose this should let my app rendered in a resizable way (non-compat-mode) for "normal" and "large" devices like nexus 7 and compat-mode for xlarge devices like nexus 10.
Unfortunately, it is not. I was wondering what's wrong with my settings, and is there any way to achieve my target.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked back, I have found out the big mistake I have made in my question. I was somehow out of my mind to think nexus 7 is of the xlarge category since I define it as a tablet. But actually it will be treated the same as Samsung Note 2. According this this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Please don't demerit my point. I don't know how to close this question anyway. I think my question itself is a good answer. If anybody want to achieve the same result.